# How can i implement.GMSMapViewDelegate in another class instead of ViewController

Tags: google-maps, swiftui

I'm working on swiftui views instead of traditional viewController, i used UIViewRepresentable protocol to wrap the GMSMapView. Now i would set a GMSMapViewDelegate to the represented mapView. the traditional way is to implement the protocol on the ViewController that contains the mapView but here while i'm using Swiftui views i'm really got lost. i tried to implement the delegate on a separate class but it did't work for e and couldn't get the current camera target when i moved it.

Please can anyone guide me, this is my first steps in iOS development.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for giving intention to my question, finally i solved it.

Just created a class that inherit from GMSMapViewDelegate and made it as an environment object so all views can access it.

best wishes to all.